# How to prevent current user get notified?

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm making an app that allows user to like and comment on other user post. I'm using Parse as my backend. I'm able to notified user everytime their post liked or commented. However if current user like or comment on their own post this current user still notified. How can I prevent this?

Here is the js code that I use:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave('Likes', function(request) {

// read pointer async
request.object.get("likedPost").fetch().then(function(like){

    // 'post' is the commentedPost object here
    var liker = like.get('createdBy');

    // proceed with the rest of your code - unchanged
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    query.equalTo('jooveUser', liker);

    Parse.Push.send({
        where: query, // Set our Installation query.
        data: {
            alert: message = request.user.get('username') + ' liked your post',
            badge: "Increment",
            sound: "facebook_pop.mp3",
            t : "l",
            lid : request.object.id,
            pid: request.object.get('likedPostId'),
            lu : request.user.get('username'),
            ca : request.object.createdAt,
            pf : request.user.get('profilePicture')
        }
    }, {
        success: function() {
            console.log("push sent")
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log("push not sent");
        }
    }); 
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the context of where this code is correctly, 
I recommend checking

```
if request.user.get("username") != Parse.CurrentUser.get("username")
```

Before sending out the push notification

Comment: I've tried that but I got error, it seems I can't retrieve the current user username.

Comment: @EgaSetyaPutra
Can you retrieve the current user at all?

Also, how do you determine who you are sending the push to?
Is that what that query is for?

If I understand this correctly, doesn't your code always send the notification to the liker, and not the likee.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your cloud function being called from? If you're calling it from your ios code, then before you call the cloud code function, just prelude it with something like this:

```
if (PFUser.currentUser?.valueForKey("userName") as! String) != (parseUser.valueForKey("userName") as! String)
```

Comment: Since you're doing this in the afterSave, you need to have access to who liked the post AND who the post belongs to. Maybe in your "likes" table, set a field for "liker" and "postOwner" and check to see if they are the same before you send the push

Comment: Alternatively, before you save the object in the swift code, check to see if currentUser is the owner of the post being liked. If so, then just don't save it.